# Cast LPCSTR to DWORD or WORD. Explanation of code and how to remove the errors when compiling with GCC?

Tags: c++, reinterpret-cast

I've been playing around with compiling some of the chromium source code base with MinGW-w64. There's some code in a pe_image.h that is giving rise to errors. They are as follows:

```
    inline bool PEImage::IsOrdinal(LPCSTR name) {
    #pragma warning(push)
    #pragma warning(disable: 4311)
    // This cast generates a warning because it is 32 bit specific.
        return reinterpret_cast<DWORD>(name) <= 0xFFFF;
    #pragma warning(pop)
    }

    inline WORD PEImage::ToOrdinal(LPCSTR name) {
        return reinterpret_cast<WORD>(name);
    }
```

I'm receiving errors such as 'cast from 'LPCSTR {aka const char*}' to 'WORD {aka short unsigned int}' loses precision [-fpermissive]' whether I compile with target triple i686-w64-mingw32 or x86_64-w64-mingw32.

I tried a variation of the answer in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558589/error-c2440-type-cast-cannot-convert-from-std-vector-iterator-ty-alloc), which compiled successfully:

```
    return *(DWORD*)(name) <= 0xFFFF;
```

The problem is that I'm not sure if that code does what the error causing code intends to do. Does it? If not, how can I fix the errors? Maybe an explanation of what the code does would help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it helps, there is indeed some weird stuff in import/export descriptors of PE files where, if a value is less than or equal to 0xFFFF then it's a word (16-bit unsigned integer), otherwise it's a pointer to a string.

Comment: Those two pieces of code do different things. The first one looks at the value of the address itself (as an integer) and compares it to `0xFFFF`. The second reinterprets what the address is *pointing to* as a DWORD, and compares *that* against `0xFFFF`. I'm not sure what the code is trying to do, but the first doesn't make much sense 90% of the time. In any case, the first should be using `std::uintptr_t` (defined in `<cstdint>`), not `DWORD`. The second is semantically fine, but may not be what you actually want.

Comment: Use DWORD_PTR instead.  Or the IS_INTRESOURCE macro.

Comment: and `static_cast` instead of `reinterpret_cast`